# Cannot get the email inside email inbox using PHP and Angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, email

I have some problem while sending email using Angular.js and PHP.Here i am getting the true value after sending the mail but I cannot get email inside the mail box. My code is below:

sendEmail.php:

```
require_once("../include/dbconfig.php");
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$to=$request->to;
$url=$request->url;
$subject=$request->subject;
$msg=$request->message;
$image=$request->image;
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$message='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Medilink Email Section</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
         Code                
        </tr>
<p><b><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">Thank you for writing to Medilink-Global.</span></b><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;"><br><br>Hi,<br><br>Your E-Voucher code is <b>'.$msg.'</b>.
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>';
$id=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($id){
    $result["msg"]="Sent successfully";
    echo json_encode($result);
}else{
    $result["msg"]="Unable to send";
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Here I am getting `Sent successfully` message in client side but this email cannot be available in my given email address inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your hosting has mail server enabled and also try using smtp connection

Comment: Can you help me how to use smtp connection.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer here you can find the code also able to debug the mailing issues